# What was the process for getting started with farming in the 1920s in Saskatchewan?

Tags: immigration, canada, 1920s

If Europeans arrived in Saskatchewan with the intention to stay permanently and become farmers, what would the process have been like in 1924? Would they have to wait or be granted land before arriving?

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy & Family History SE! Have you looked at http://www.saskhomesteads.com/ and  https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Saskatchewan_Land_and_Property_Records and http://www.familyhistoryalive.com/Prairie-Land-Grants-and-Homesteading--Manitoba-Saskatchewan-and-Alberta.html ? These and more resources can be found by googling - homesteading in Saskatchewan